# Why are my subarrays not being pushed correctly into parent array? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i am implementing bubblesort algorithm using ReactJS.  In my state, i have an array of 3 objects initially in descending order by the 'num' property.  I have a button on my screen to click which i want to run the bubblesort function i created.  I want to keep track of each iteration of the bubblesort and add it to a parent array.  However, after i run my bubblesort function, it console logs the parent array with subarrays but all the subarrays are showing sorted order instead of showing each iteration.  Can anyone see what i am not understanding?  Thanks.

EDIT: Updated Code Snippet.  I have fixed issue i was having and am now logging each iteration of bubblesort.  I have the 'compare' property of each object set to 'no' initially but want to set which two are being compared to 'yes' in each iteration (subarray).  I haven't been able to solve this.  Every objects' compare property in every iteration is getting set to 'yes' instead of just the two being compared.  Any ideas?

EDIT: Update Code Snippet.  Have a working solution.  But is there a better solution than having to JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) multiple times?  Thanks.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    array: [
      { index: 0, num: 6, compare: 'no'},
      { index: 1, num: 5, compare: 'no'},
      { index: 2, num: 4, compare: 'no'},
      { index: 3, num: 3, compare: 'no'},
      { index: 4, num: 2, compare: 'no'},
      { index: 5, num: 1, compare: 'no'},
      ]
    }
    this.onBtnClick = this.onBtnClick.bind(this);
  }
 
  onBtnClick() {
  let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.array));

    let output = [JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(copy))];
    
   for(let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < copy.length-i-1; j++) {
       copy.forEach(item => { item.compare = 'no' });
       copy[j].compare = 'yes';
        copy[j + 1].compare = 'yes';
        if (copy[j].num > copy[j + 1].num) {
        let temp = copy[j + 1];
         copy[j + 1] = copy[j];
         copy[j] = temp;
       }
        output.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(copy)));
     }
   }
    console.log(output);

  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.onBtnClick}>Click Me to console log</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were logging it outside both the loops whereas you should log it inside the first loop but outside second one to see each iteration.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      array: [{
          index: 0,
          num: 3,
          otherProp: 'test'
        },
        {
          index: 1,
          num: 2,
          otherProp: 'test'
        },
        {
          index: 2,
          num: 1,
          otherProp: 'test'
        },
      ]
    }
    this.onBtnClick = this.onBtnClick.bind(this);
  }

  onBtnClick() {
    let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.array));
    let newCopy = [copy];
    for (let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < copy.length - i - 1; j++) {
        copy[j].otherProp = 'notest';
        if (copy[j].num > copy[j + 1].num) {
          let temp = copy[j + 1];
          copy[j + 1] = copy[j];
          copy[j] = temp;
        }

        newCopy.push(copy);
      }
       console.log(newCopy);
    }
    
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      h2 > Test < /h2> <
      button type = 'button'
      onClick = {
        this.onBtnClick
      } > Click Me to console log < /button> <
      /div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < TodoApp / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

arrays are reference types in js, therefore if you save the same array in an array, but console it out at the end the last array will be outputted multiple times, if you want to output an array of history you should make a copy of each array when pushing it into the "history" array